# Adding z values to contours without attribute data

Tags: contour

I have a set of contour lines with 5 meter interval which doesn't have any height set in the attribute data.

Now I'd like to assign (preferably automatic) z values to these contours since I want to change the interval to 10 meters. Does anyone know how to do this using open source tools?

Almost ten years ago I found an application where I could assign height to contours by dragging a line through some contour lines and tell the app what the interval was and the height of the first contour line. I don't remember what the app was called but that one would help me even though it would be nicer to add elevation info from a dem or something.

Comment: How many lines are you talking about,  maybe edit your question with a screen shot of the size of the problem you are facing?

Comment: A couple of hundreds.